# Enhanced Table extension for TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I'm fairly new to TYPO3 and as far as I can see it's pretty poorly maintained as far as documentation goes. Some of the tutorials and documentation are almost a decade old and I was wondering if anyone here knows of any useful extensions that could enhance the standard content tables in the backend.

I have some tables that contain a bunch of links with images. A sort of categories gallery with thumbnails if you will.

The point being that at some point this gets passed on to a client who won't know what to do with HTML markup and i was wondering if anyone knew of 1) a good WYSIWYG table editor extension and 2) a categories gallery plugin with the option to add thumbnails to each category.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Look for some of the more recent plugins.  I don't usually go back more than a year or two when searching for an extension.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking to do, but did you know you can arrange the standard image elements in different ways, linking each image to a different page, kind of like what can be seen at:  http://www.thedemo.ca/demonstrations/image-and-text-alignment.html

Simon